# After Upgrade + 2 days later. No Bios, no Grub

Tags: 13.04, upgrade

I did my upgrade from Ubuntu 12 to Ubuntu 13 last friday night. Saturday and Sunday it worked not too bad (except that the keyboard layout has changed). I restarted the laptop and all worked.

Then yesterday night I started the PC and again the keyboard layout issue. I restarted the PC and from then on, I only see a black screen. No BIOS, no GRUB... nothing only black screen.

I have a HP laptop with a ATI radeon graphics.

What can I now? I can't login even by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>.

Comment: Does your laptop even start as of now?

Comment: Which HP laptop?

Answer (score 0):

No Bios..?

Check that first. When you boot, hit

DEL
F1
F2
ESC
F10

It should be one of those ([HP reference](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-Systems-and-Software/how-to-access-the-bios/td-p/1301371)).

Assuming you still have a BIOS, next step would be to boot from LiveCD and most likely fix something with GRUB.

Comment: well I tried what you suggested...but nothing to do; i tried to connect my laptop to another monitor and again nothing....I can't understand if it's my laptop problem or update problem...what else can I try? Angelo

Comment: If you cannot even get to BIOS, then I would say your laptop is bricked.